# How to use Two NSOutlineview in one view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nsoutlineview

How to use Two NSOutlineview in one view ?
 if i am using rowAtpoint() method in one NSoutlineview i m getting proper result, but on another NSoutlineview which is in same view not giving proper result

Comment: Can you show us the piece of code where you are calling the views' `rowAtPoint:` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSSplitView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Take a look at [SplitViews sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SplitViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011336).
[image: NSSplitView]